# Google Maps not showing on Xcode Simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios-simulator, google-maps-sdk-ios

Google maps is not showing on Xcode simulator. I've tried it on my actual iPhone however and it works just fine. I then followed this query up apple developer support however, they mentioned that they were unable to help as I initially thought it may have been a simulator issue.

Can anyone advise as to what the issue could be?

The google markers are all showing but just the map view itself shows up blank. Ive tried disabling and re-enabling the Google Maps SDK on the google api console. I've even tried creating new API keys to use but this did not change.

PS. This never used to be an issue before Xcode 9.

[Screenshot of Xcode simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwH4B.png)

Here is a snippet of code that I've used to add Google maps to the application:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

  _mkap=[[GMSMapView alloc]initWithFrame:_mapView.bounds];
  _mkap.myLocationEnabled = YES;
  _mkap.delegate=self;
  NSError *error;
  NSURL *url1 =[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"map_white" withExtension:@"json"];
  GMSMapStyle *style = [GMSMapStyle styleWithContentsOfFileURL:url1 error:&error];

  if (!style) {
    NSLog(@"The style definition could not be loaded: %@", error);
  }
  _mkap.mapStyle = style;
  [_mapView addSubview:_mkap];
  _arrayPolylineGreen = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
```

Comment: Are you certain you've [added your API key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/get-api-key#add_key) to your app? And that it is correctly restricted? Have you enabled billing on your project? Do you get any errors?

Comment: I have added my API key. As the actual map view shows on my physical iPhone device when I run the build but for some reason, this isn’t reflected on Xcode simulator. Hence I was wondering if this is something to do with settings within xcode that I need to tweak?

Comment: Thanks for your response by the way Evan!

Comment: Sure! Okay so let me get back to you after doing some testing on my end. In the meantime can you please look into https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#maps-sdk-ios and can you try (1) creating a brand new (unrestricted) API key (2) inserting this new API key into your app and (3) re-building your app? And do please double check that your billing account is in good standing and that Maps SDK for IOS is enabled on your project.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is a scenario you are in. I faced the same issue with google maps displayed as a gray box in the IOS simulator.
The root cause was the netskope client running in my mac. Once that was disabled, maps started showing streets and roads.

[image]

Netskope client details - https://docs.netskope.com/en/netskope-client.html